# what is the use of PricebookEntryHistory__c

Tags: pricebook

what is this PricebookEntryHistory__c object used for in Salesforce? Everytime i insert/update a 'pricebooktentry' via coding i have to create a PricebookEntryHistory__c?

Comment: Maybe a custom field add to the `Pricebooktentry` object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom, not a standard object. You can see this by it's name ending with __c

So there is really no general answer on how it should be used we can provide (beside guessing).

In the setup > create > objects you can see who created it. Best thing to ask this person on how it is or should be used.

Comming back to blind guessing: it could have been used for analytical snapshots as described here

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US